# How to merge two intersecting arrays via es6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays that have properties: `minValue`, `maxValue`, `avgValue`.  I would like to write a very clean approach to identifying which objects match (the displayName) in the array and then assign the values of the new array to the old (minPrice, maxPrice, avgPrice).

I have this code so far

```
export interface Player {
    displayName: string;
    MinPrice: number;
    MaxPrice: number;
    AvgPrice: number;}

export const MERGE_PLAYER_STATS = (playerStat: Player[], auctionStat: Player[]): any => {
      const reducer = (playerStat, auctionStat) => {
        playerStat.MinPrice = auctionStat.minPrice,
        playerStat.MaxPrice = auctionStat.maxPrice,
        playerStat.AvgPrice = auctionStat.avgPrice,
        playerStat.Team = auctionStat.team;
     }
      return reducer(playerStat, auctionStat =>
        filter(auctionStat, playerStat => auctionStat.displayName.includes(playerStat.displayName)));
}


Input: two different set of player arrays that have common display Names.  
playerStat: [] = [];
auctionStat: [] = [];

playerStat.push( {
displayName: "Josh Allen",
minPrice: "",
maxPrice: "",
avgPrice: ""
}, 
{
displayName: "No One",
minPrice: "",
maxPrice: "",
avgPrice: ""
});

auctionStat.push( {
displayName: "Josh Allen",
minPrice: 1,
maxPrice: 2,
avgPrice: 1
}, 
{
displayName: "No One 2",
minPrice: 1,
maxPrice: 1,
avgPrice: 2
});
```

The output should only have Josh Allen stats being updated from blank values to 1,2,1 respectively.

Please let me know what your clean approach this.  FYI, this code is not returning what I want it to.

Comment: please share the two arrays

Comment: You mean, get the duplicated objects?

Comment: No. I want to find intersecting objects that have the same displayName. and reassign the value of the first array w/ the second array (minPrice, maxPrice, avgPrice) values.

Comment: @ChristopherYou Please add any relevant code that makes the question clearer to the question

Comment: @ChristopherYou not particularly! Example input and expected output would be nice. Think of it like writing a unit test that is currently failing, and you want some help getting it to pass.

Comment: @ChristopherYou Thanks for adding input / output. Are new values merged in, or do you just want to update existing values?

Comment: @ChristopherYou Also, are there some properties you don't want to update, or are you happy updating all of them? I have a suggestion for you, depending on the answers to these questions.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I simply want to re assign the "Price" values with from the auctionStat to the playerstat array. So update, to be exact.  I'm not sure I want to update all the properties.  I simplified this problem as my API call has a different property structure than the one listed above.  Maybe if you can offer different solutions, I can give you my two cents.  But preferably, just 3 values need to be updated.  Thanks Kurt. PS. I wanted to avoid using a for loop as it is brute forcing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach would be to simply write a mapping function that copies in new objects based on matching keys.

Given an interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
  key: string;
  value: number;
}
```

And two arrays:

```
const existingArray: MyInterface[] = [
  { key: 'a', value: 1 },
  { key: 'b', value: 2 },
  { key: 'c', value: 3 }
];

const newArray: MyInterface[] = [
  { key: 'b', value: 20 },
  { key: 'c', value: 30 },
  { key: 'd', value: 40 }
];
```

**Expected output**

I want to update the `existingArray` with the values from `newArray` where the keys match.

- If a value isn't found in `newArray`, the existing item is untouched.
- If a new value is found in `newArray`, it isn't merged in to `oldArray`
- All property values are to be overwritten

My expected output is:

```
const expected = [
  { key: 'a', value: 1 },
  { key: 'b', value: 20 },
  { key: 'c', value: 30 }
];
```

**Solution**

I would achieve this by using this merge function. It is just a javascript array map:

```
private merge<T>(existing: T[], updated: T[], getKey: (t: T) => string): T[] {
  // start with the existing array items
  return existing.map(item => {
    // get the key using the callback
    const key: string = getKey(item);
    // find the matching item by key in the updated array
    const matching: T = updated.find(x => getKey(x) === key);
    if (matching) {
      // if a matching item exists, copy the property values to the existing item
      Object.assign(item, matching);
    }
    return item;
  });
}
```

I have made it generic to allow you to use it with any type. All you need to do it provide the 2 arrays, and a callback to identify the key.

I would use it to created a merged array like this:

```
const merged = this.merge(existingArray, newArray, x => x.key);
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nn8hit

**A word of warning**

This wouldn't scale well with very large arrays. If you are using large arrays, I would optimise by creating indexes of type `Map<string, T>`, to keep the number of loops fixed. This implementation is out of scope of this question.

Edit:

If you only want to update specific values, you could pass in an update callback:

```
private merge<T>(existing: T[], updated: T[], getKey: (t: T) => string, 
  update: (item, matching) => void
): T[] {
  return existing.map(item => {
    const key: string = getKey(item);
    const matching: T = updated.find(x => getKey(x) === key);
    if (matching) {
      update(item, matching);
    }
    return item;
  });
}
```

And call it like this:

```
const merged = this.merge(existingArray, newArray, x => x.key, 
  (item, matching) => item.value = matching.value);
```

Comment: I actually want to update every object in the array with a matching key.  With your solution, I would have to use a for loop with your merge call.  Does this sound like the best solution?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a proposed solution, if I've understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.assign()

Ex: oldArray = Object.assign(oldArray, newArray)

Comment: I know the question isn't clear, but how is this solving the problem? This would just overwrite the oldArray with values from newArray at matching indexes. Object.assign doesn't automatically understand the internal structure of the contents of the arrays.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Am I on the right track with writing a reducer and trying to filter it?

Comment: To copy values from new array to old array this is the approach it will identify the keys also if there is an extra key it will add that also

Answer (score 0):

```
playerStat.forEach((initItem) => {
  let result = auctionStat.filter((item) => (
    initItem.displayName === item.displayName 
  ))
  // let me suppose the same displayName only has one
  result.length && Object.assign(initItem, result[0])
})
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.